# How to load GTM with NextJS Script component?

Tags: next.js, google-tag-manager

I recently came across the script component in NextJS (https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script)

I wanted to know if it's possible to load Google tag manager using this component.

Comment: Yes, it is possible - Next.js provides an example project on how to do it: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-google-tag-manager.

Comment: Not sure you version but you can take a look about this too. 
https://www.learnbestcoding.com/post/9/easiest-way-to-integrate-google-analytics-with-react-js-and-next-js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the following `<Script>` tags within your _app.tsx file.

```
// pages/_app.tsx
export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppPropsWithLayout) {
  const getLayout = Component.getLayout ?? ((page) => page)

  return getLayout(
    <>
      <Script id="google-site-tag"
        strategy='lazyOnload'
        src={`https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=${GOOGLE_TAG_ID}`}
      />
      <Script id="google-analytics" strategy='lazyOnload'>
        {`
          window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
          function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
          gtag('js', new Date());
          gtag('config', '${GOOGLE_TAG_ID}');
        `}
      </Script>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </>
  )
}
```